# Cache Money vs DB-level indices?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, caching, indexing

Does Cache Money gem eliminate the need for DB-level indices (the ones typically used to improve query retrieval)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caching = answers to you query are retrieved from cache (RAM), if they're there. The database is only accessed on cache miss.

Indexing = helping the database answer some queries (much) faster (a simplistic definition, but enough for my purpose here).

So, the cache speeds up queries by not hitting the database at all, whereas the index speeds up queries that go through the cache and hit the database.

The benefit you could get from caching depends on the specifics of your application. If most queries ask for the same data, or you have much few updates than reads, it should prove a good idea to use a caching layer. However, even in the best scenarios I've seen, 15-20% of queries still reach the database. That means that you cannot rely on caching alone.

But most important - database indices are simple to define and usually require zero maintenance unless you become huge. Caching otoh is far more complicated - for the cache-money gem you'll need to install, configure and maintain memcached. That isn't rocket science, but still adds another layer of complexity on top of your database. In other words, this is usually premature optimization.
I recommend that you start with DB indices and only add a caching layer when you find that you really need it.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing can replace the need for an index.

A caching layer may change the workload and lower the load on the database, thus mitigating the impact of missing indexes. With a caching layer you may need other indexes for optimal performance, but you still need them if you want to have the best possible performance.